# Socket.io connection only establishes on server reset (nodejitsu) works fine locally?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, nodejitsu

So basically I'm making a simple RTS board game with node.js/express/socket.io for a learning experience. So far it's going really well and I though I was almost there working purely on the localhost. Deployed it to nodejitsu and loaded the page up, but the server isn't sending the initial server data to the client. If (while the page is open, no refresh) I reset the server it then establishes connection and the whole thing works as expected, but a client visiting the server doesn't do it.

Server init code:

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);


server.listen(8080);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function(req, res){

    res.sendfile("index.html");

});

app.get('/RTSwords', function(req, res){

    //res.sendfile("public\\RTSwords.html");
    res.sendfile("RTSwords.html");

});
```

Server socket.io code

```
// define interactions with client
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    //send them board and first seven tiles.

    socket.emit('serverNews', {'game': JSON.stringify(gameBoard), 'newTiles': randomTileString(7)});
```

And client socket.io code

```
var socket = io.connect('http://MYURLHERE');
.......
socket.on('serverNews', function(data){
            update(data);
        });
```

So yeah,in summary it works locally, works when page is loaded and server is restarted (I'm just "jistu deploy"ing to do that) but not when server is running then page is loaded.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client use `io.connect()` , if you need more help join #nodejitsu on IRC, http://webchat.jit.su or irc://chat.freenode.net/#nodejitsu

Comment: Thanks very much- didn't know that was an option. Unfortunately still has not solved my problem...will keep looking. Also thanks for the IRC links, just jumped on seems to be the place to be. OK Got it worked  out, for those playing at home - I was starting the client listener socket.on(blah) in a function, and it didnt like that- moved it to the initializing stage and it seems to be working great guns now.